# Angular JS route doesn't display my html files on div

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a menu and display all my .html in a div section.
But when i click on link, nothing display - no reaction.

Here my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" ng-app="PrincipaleApp">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="format.css" media="all" />

    <title>TitreV3</title>
  </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>


<body>

<p class="titre">Titre V3</p>


<table class="structure">
<tr>
<td class="structuremenu">


 <div class="menu" ng-init="names=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five']">  
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
 <td>
{{ x }}
</td>
 <td><a href="#/{{ x }}_OK">OK</a></td>
 <td><a href="#/{{ x }}_NotOK">KO</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</td>
    <td class="structurecontenu">
<div ng-view></div>      
</td>
    </tr>
</table>


  </body>
</html>
```

Here my app.js:

```
var PrincipaleApp = angular.module('PrincipaleApp', ['ngRoute', 'PrincipaleAppControllers']);

PrincipaleApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/One_OK', {
      templateUrl : 'One_OK.html',
      controller: 'PrincipaleCtrl'
    }).
    when('/One_NotOK', {
      templateUrl : 'One_NotOK.html',
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo : '/'
    });
}]);


var lignes = angular.module('PrincipaleApp', []);
```

Here my controllers.js

```
var PrincipaleAppControllers = angular.module('PrincipaleAppControllers', []);

PrincipaleAppControllers.controller('PrincipaleCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'world';
}]);
```

And here One_OK.html

```
<div ng-controller="PrincipaleCtrl">
  <label>Nom :</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <br />
  <h2>Hello {{ name }}!</h2>
</div>
```

For me, ngroute is okay in my app.js

Maybe div my ng-view doesn't function correctly in a table ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below line from your code

```
var lignes = angular.module('PrincipaleApp', []);
```

Plunker code - https://plnkr.co/edit/FQ0jOQErIhBgTyVQg7mn?p=preview

Same module name - PrincipaleApp was created twice

Comment: Great ! It's works ! Thank you for taking some time for that :)

Comment: if my post helped your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: Off course, but where i can do that ? Edit: Hum i think it's okay ?